# speedup preview of video while it is being downloaded using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-streaming

I need to download cca 10min clip from a much longer video from server every day. So to save bandwidth and time, I want to see a preview and stop right after the desired part ends while it is still downloading.

I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i "https://example.com/video.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a copy -y -f mpegts - | ffmpeg -i - -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts e:\_%datetime%.ts -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts pipe:play | ffplay -an -i pipe:play
```

The problem is when it plays the preview is played in realtime, but I want the preview to be faster, preferably same speed as it is downloading.
Is it possible to speed-up the preview video?